# Add Item from EditText to RecyclerView

Tags: android

I am making a project for my college. It has a notice page where anyone can post notice. The notice page has a recyclerview so that all the notices posted can be viewed by all users using the app, as if the text is stuck permanent to the page. The notice gets saved in the database successfully, but I dont want to show the notice from the database, its just for project purpose. But ever time on clicking the post button the app force closes. What is wrong in the code. Please Help. Below are my files.

activity_notice.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="RECENT NOTICES"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#ff0612"
        android:textSize="30dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/noticeText"
        android:hint="Post Notice"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/sndnoticeBut"
        android:src="@drawable/send1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        android:onClick="addItem"/>
</RelativeLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="155dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:onClick="addItem" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

noticeview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="155dp"
        android:id="@+id/noticetext"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Notice.java

```
package com.salesiancollege.www.salesiani_smart;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis;

public class Notice extends Activity
{
    ImageButton notbut;
    EditText nottxt;
    String Post;
    Context ctx=this;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private CustomRecyclerAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private List<Data> mData = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notice);

        notbut = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sndnoticeBut);
        nottxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noticeText);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        // If the size of views will not change as the data changes.
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        // Setting the LayoutManager.
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    }
            public void addItem(View v)
            {

               Post = nottxt.getText().toString();
                // Add data locally to the list.
                Data dataToAdd = new Data(nottxt.getText().toString());
                mData.add(dataToAdd);

                // Update adapter.
                mAdapter.addItem(mData.size()-1, dataToAdd);
               BackGround b = new BackGround();
               b.execute(Post);
            }


    class BackGround extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String nottxt = params[0];
            String data="";
            int tmp;

            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2/salesiancollege/notice.php");
                String urlParams = "nottxt="+nottxt;

                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                os.write(urlParams.getBytes());
                os.flush();
                os.close();
                InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                while((tmp=is.read())!=-1){
                    data+= (char)tmp;
                }
                is.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();

                return data;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Exception: "+e.getMessage();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Exception: "+e.getMessage();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            if(s.equals("")){
                s="Notice Posted.";
            }
            Toast.makeText(ctx, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Data.java

```
package com.salesiancollege.www.salesiani_smart;

import android.app.Activity;

/**
 * Created by PARTHO on 11-06-2016.
 */
public class Data
{
    public String text;
    public Data(String text)
    {
        this.text = text;

    }

}
```

CustomRecyclerAdapter.java

```
package com.salesiancollege.www.salesiani_smart;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


public class CustomRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolder>
{
    private List<Data> mData = Collections.emptyList();

    public CustomRecyclerAdapter()
    {
        // Pass context or other static stuff that will be needed.
    }
    public void updateList(List<Data> data)
    {
        mData = data;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public void addItem(int position, Data data)
    {
        mData.add(position, data);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int position)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.noticeview, viewGroup, false);
        return new RecyclerViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder, int position)
    {
        viewHolder.notice.setText(mData.get(position).text);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return mData.size();
    }


}
```

RecyclerViewHolder.java

```
package com.salesiancollege.www.salesiani_smart;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public TextView notice;


    public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        notice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.noticetext);

    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
06-11 15:54:05.650      335-722/? V/WindowManager﹕ Adding window Window{7b97cc0 u0 com.salesiancollege.www.salesiani_smart/com.salesiancollege.www.salesiani_smart.Notice} at 3 of 8 (after Window{293060cb u0 com.salesiancollege.www.salesiani_smart/com.salesiancollege.www.salesiani_smart.studentDashboard})
06-11 15:54:05.959    1291-1309/? W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-11 15:54:05.960    1291-1309/? W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb4b7cb80, error=EGL_SUCCESS
06-11 15:54:06.087    1291-1291/? E/RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout
06-11 15:54:06.751    1291-1291/? E/RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout
06-11 15:54:06.783      335-358/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed com.salesiancollege.www.salesiani_smart/.Notice: +2s147ms
06-11 15:54:13.690    1291-1291/? E/RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout
06-11 15:54:13.895    1291-1291/? E/RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout
06-11 15:54:14.209    1291-1291/? E/RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout
06-11 15:54:14.364    1291-1291/? E/RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout
06-11 15:54:14.562    1291-1291/? E/RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout
06-11 15:54:23.115      335-383/? W/AudioTrack﹕ AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
06-11 15:54:23.131    1291-1291/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
06-11 15:54:23.182    1291-1291/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.salesiancollege.www.salesiani_smart, PID: 1291
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4020)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.salesiancollege.www.salesiani_smart.CustomRecyclerAdapter.addItem(int, com.salesiancollege.www.salesiani_smart.Data)' on a null object reference
            at com.salesiancollege.www.salesiani_smart.Notice.addItem(Notice.java:83)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Logcat when the app force closes;

Comment: If comment  Data dataToAdd = new Data(nottxt.getText().toString());
                mData.add(dataToAdd);

                // Update adapter.
                mAdapter.addItem(mData.size()-1, dataToAdd);

Comment: In my notice.java, then it adds to database, otherwise not.